Что произошло с вопросами?

Если нажать на гиперссылку перекинет на SE с объяснениями, почему меня ограничили в функции задать вопрос, но у меня всего был один вопрос с рейтингом 0.

Потому что не надо обманывать систему и создавать новые учётки, если старые заблокированы/удалены после блокировки публикаций.
